# Zooming Issue : While Zooming.... Canvas background image is not zooming

Tags: javascript, canvas, zooming

Image on canvas with :

```
function make_base(){
    base_image = new Image();
    base_image.src = 'bk.jpg';
    base_image.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(base_image, 0, 0, 1000, 800);
    }
}
```

But I am also adding the circles on canvas.

As I am adding image and circles both elements... Circles are getting overlap with image.

What can be done?

Comment: I cannot see your code for zooming or circles anywhere..

Comment: i am not expert in this area but consider changing the width and height of image depending on zoom level

Comment: When you have set ctx.scale() you will need to *redraw* everything. Just setting scale doesn't do anything to the canvas. It just prepares for what will happen in the *next* draw. But this is an assumption until you can provide more code to analyze.

Comment: document.getElementById("plus").addEventListener("click", function(){
   scale /= scaleMultiplier;
   //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
   draw(dataJSON, scale, translatePos);
  }, false);          In this I am redrawing with draw(dataJSON, scale, translatePos); function . As I added the image with above with new Image() the how to use redraw for the same?

Comment: How to draw circle on background image of Canvas and when I zoom then background image and circle also need to Zoom